# HANA index server won't start

Tags: hana

I've installed HANA Express edition from binary in a VM (4 cores and 8GB of RAM) when I run `HDB info` it give me

```
USER       PID  PPID %CPU    VSZ   RSS COMMAND
hxeadm   12253 12252  0.0 115512  2024 -bash
hxeadm   12305 12253  0.0 113256  1616  \_ /bin/sh /usr/sap/HXE/HDB01/HDB info
hxeadm   12340 12305  0.0 151060  1804      \_ ps fx -U hxeadm -o user,pid,ppid,pcpu,vsz,rss,args
hxeadm    4641     1  0.0  23044  1708 sapstart pf=/usr/sap/HXE/SYS/profile/HXE_HDB01_amds-bd
hxeadm    4788  4641  0.0 232064 36552  \_ /usr/sap/HXE/HDB01/amds-bd/trace/hdb.sapHXE_HDB01 -d -nw -f /usr/sap/HXE/HDB01/amds-bd/daemon.ini pf=/usr/sap/HXE/SYS/profile/H

hxeadm    5239  4788  6.2 3184688 2271760      \_ hdbnameserver
hxeadm   10672  4788  1.1 1121576 416644      \_ hdbcompileserver
hxeadm   10681  4788  0.2 1028188 297320      \_ hdbpreprocessor
hxeadm   10826  4788  0.3 1336672 519228      \_ hdbwebdispatcher
hxeadm    3562     1  0.0 432156 26000 /usr/sap/HXE/HDB01/exe/sapstartsrv pf=/usr/sap/HXE/SYS/profile/HXE_HDB01_amds-bd -D -u hxeadm
```

as you can see, the hdbindexserver is not started, and to be more sure I've checked the port number 30015, ant it's not used at all.

I've tried with the Virtual machine provisioned by HANA installer, but I've got the same results.

My question is how to start the index server?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a RAM problem,

I added some more RAM, now with 18GB of RAM everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's ok. HXE is installed as MDC system by default (with tenants disabled if I remember it right). In the system DB the nameserver takes over the task of the index server.
Check those links:

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3961778

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DbaO_-Hlq98

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I created a tenant database, but when I start it I get:
`ALTER SYSTEM START DATABASE app1;
* 2: general error: Database could not be started;start databaseServer for database=3 on : app-bd:30040 failed SQLSTATE: HY000`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an OS level access, you can try to start it manually:

```
/usr/sap/HXE/HDB01/exe/hdbindexserver
```

and see why it fails in logs, which are located at

```
/usr/sap/HXE/HDB01/<name_of_your_server>/trace/indexserver_alert_sixtb.trc
```

You can check other files in the same folder as well.

It is also possible to start indexserver from HANA Studio. Right click on the instance (with SYSTEM user) --> Configuration and Monitoring --> Open Administration --> Landscape

The logs are available under --> Diagnosis Files in the Administration.

Answer (score 0):

New comers to this issue... for the sake of consistency you can allocate a dedicated Memory in "Docker Desktop > Preferences > Resource > Memory" (usually Tenant creation consumes memory during the initial setup as it fires up the Indexserver taking up to 12GB of Ram). Cheers